# decode json format data sent via url

Tags: php, json

consider the following url

`index.php?json={uid:guest|10001441}`

I am not able to decode the data .
 I need the output as `{"uid":"guest|10001441"}`.

The code i m using is

```
if (isset($_GET['json']))
{
   $url_data = $_GET['json'];
   $decoded_data = json_decode($url_data,true);
   var_dump($decoded_data);
}
```

But it gives me output as `NULL`. What am i doing wrong?? Do i need to pass data in a different format??

Comment: what does var_dump($_GET['json']) produce?

Comment: string(18) "{uid:guest|10001441}"

Comment: @Mayur You are getting wrong json data its not a valid  json string .
check where it is being generated and correct them.

Comment: What keeps you from using $_POST?

Comment: in the url the json is invalid, u forgot the quotes... better if you send by post no ?

Comment: why you are not using POST place of get?

Comment: i need to pass as GET .. but if i include the quotes,i get string(26) "{\"uid\":\"guest|100000\"}" on doing `var_dump($_GET['json'])`

Comment: i added the quotes and then removed the `\\` using str_replace. Have not accepted any answer but have voted up the answers that suggested the quote thing.

Answer (score 2):

It seems impossible to decode a JSON string without double quotes, as it's hard to determine whether a JSON string `"{A:B:C}"` is encoded from `{"A":"B:C"}` or from `{"A:B":"C"}`

You can use urlencode() to encode the JSON string or just ignore the extreme cases and add the double quotes manually to make the JSON string valid, hope this help :D

Answer (score 1):

If you pass it like this it will work: `?json={"uid":"guest|10001441"}`

But I am not sure whether it is a proper method.

Comment: are quotes allowed in url..i dnt think so

Comment: It works for me, you can use url_encode / decode , Still I am not sure it is a proper method

Comment: It works for me, you can use url_encode / decode , Still I am not sure it is a proper method

Comment: I just used your code and in url I added the quotes as in my answer thats it and worked

Answer (score 1):

The data you're passing is not valid JSON. It doesn't have double quotes around it currently. Try this:

```
if (isset($_GET['json']))
{
   $url_data = '"'.$_GET['json'].'"';
   $decoded_data = json_decode($url_data,true);
   var_dump($decoded_data);
}
```

**Output:**

```
string(20) "{uid:guest|10001441}"
```

Also, I'd suggest using `POST` instead of `GET` here.

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you have in your URL is not valid. PHP's json_decode looks for double quotes around the `uid` and it's value.

EDIT: Rather than storing the data in the URL as json could you not store the data as key value pairs such as

```
?uid=value
```

And then you could do something like

```
$data = json_encode( $_GET );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can encode url parameter with base64_encode()

```
$json=base64_encode('{"uid":"guest|10001441"}');
```

url will look like this

```
index.php?json=eyJ1aWQiOiJndWVzdHwxMDAwMTQ0MSJ9
```

then do like this :-

```
if (isset($_GET['json']))
{
   $url_data = base64_decode($_GET['json']);
   $decoded_data = json_decode($url_data,true);
   var_dump($decoded_data);
}
```

Comment: That won't help if the original data isn't valid JSON.

Comment: @Barmar thanks to remind ,but i said it in comments that use a valid json string.

Comment: OK. But if you're going to encode a URL parameter, `urlencode()` is the usual format, so that it's still somewhat readable.

Comment: @Barmar if we use urlencode will be somting like this  %7B%22uid%22%3A%22guest%7C10001441%22%7D, means to say use encoding .I would like it to send via post.